# Efficient way of gettting a single example of a row when using hashes

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

My database has a staging table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE featureMappings (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  visitId bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  featureId bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  textValue text DEFAULT NULL,
  hashTextValue char(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MD5(textValue)) VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));
ALTER TABLE featureMappings
ADD INDEX fsHashTextValue (featureId, hashTextValue)
```

In a typical run this table has approximately 40 - 100 million rows. There are a lot of duplicate text values so I am using the hashTextValue key to be able to index on this column.

The following query takes about 25 seconds to run:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS
SELECT 
  featureId,
  hashTextValue
FROM 
  featureMappings
GROUP BY featureId, hashTextValue
```

**Question**

I'd like to extract the value in the `textValue` column alongside the `featureId` and `hashTextValue` columns.

I have tried two approaches. Both of these dramatically increased the query time, so I'm looking for a better solution.

*Slow Option 1 - Adding `textValue` to the query*

When running the belo change to the query, the time to process went from 25 seconds to about 10 minutes. I've tried to google how `textValue` is retrieved when not using an aggregate function, but could not find a clear answer.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS
SELECT 
  featureId,
  hashTextValue,
  textValue # I also tried MIN(textValue)
FROM 
  featureMappings
GROUP BY featureId, hashTextValue
```

*Complicated Option 2: Iterative Update*

My preferred approach is to iterate over the unique combinations of the first query and then run a loop over the following queries:

```
SELECT featureId, hashTextValue INTO @fid, @htv 
FROM temp
WHERE textValue is NULL and hashTextValue IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1;

SELECT textValue 
INTO @textValue
FROM featureMappings 
WHERE featureId = @fid and hashTextValue = @htv
LIMIT 1;

UPDATE temp
SET textValue = @textValue
WHERE featureId = @fid AND hashTextValue = @htv;
```

*Server Configuration*

This is being run on AWS RDS Aurora based on Mysql 5.7. The server has limited (2GB) memory and usually has less freeable memory than the index size on the table.

Comment: Hashes are very random.  How big (GB) is each table?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?  (I am checking on the cachability of things.)

Comment: It seems like there are many steps in this pipeline; perhaps you should not focus on this one step, but instead ask whether the entire algorithm can be sped up.

Comment: Most queries in the entire pipeline take seconds to run. This stage is the slowest of all. The entire table has about 40M rows, however I do expect it to increase to serveral 100M rows. The cluster size / `innodb_buffer_pool` is configured to be able to hold suffcient memory to store the index (several times over) but not all of the text values. Running explain it appears that when using `MIN(textValue)` or just `textValue` as a column under select, all rows are being read, which makes the query so inefficient, I'm essentially looking for the best way onely read one row per group.

Comment: See if my addition to my Answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Dedup as you load.  This is trivially done by making the PK of `featureMappings` be `PRIMARY KEY(featureId, hashTextValue)` and using `INSERT IGNORE` when loading the staging table.

Plan B:  (Assuming there is something preventing Plan A)  Change the table have these indexes.

```
  PRIMARY KEY (featureId, hashTextValue, id),
  INDEX(id)
```

This still has the dups, but I am unclear on what needs to happen next.

**Further...**

```
SELECT featureId, hashTextValue INTO @fid, @htv 
    FROM temp
    WHERE textValue is NULL and hashTextValue IS NOT NULL
    LIMIT 1;
```

This has the problem of getting slower and slower as you eat through the items that match.  It would be better to add an explicit `PRIMARY KEY` and walk through `temp`.  In fact, it will be an order of magnitude faster (if `temp` is large).  Let's say `id` is the PK; then:

```
SELECT @id := id, @fid := featureId, @htv := hashTextValue INTO
    FROM temp
    WHERE textValue is NULL and hashTextValue IS NOT NULL
      AND id > @id   -- this picks up 'where you left off'
    LIMIT 1;
```

(Initialize with `SET @id := 0;`)

Now that you have the `id`, the `UPDATE` becomes simpler and faster.

Comment: I already have an index on `hashTextValue` and `id`. retrieving the uinque combinations is reasonably fast. My issue is that I also want to retrieve the `textValue` (which is a `text` so I cannot index it) this increases the query time by a factor of about 20x.

Comment: I like that approach. storing the ID of the last run. to prevent having to run this again makes a lot of sense to me.